# How to make custom ads not google ads on ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ads, ngcordova

I want to add advertising for some companies in my Ionic app . I tried admob but it for google ads.I want to  show specific ads picture with text or video for local company.
the user sees it and he can dismiss this ads or click on it.I use  Ionic Framework for my app .any help or information will be great.thanks

Comment: See https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Angular.js,-Ionic-apps. Admob has mediation feature, where you can specify where are the ads comming from. If your ads are comming from an external source, you could use mediation to show only the ads you want to show.

Comment: Thanks @Miquel    for your comment, I get to Mediation page in google admob .I found campaigns and New ad network.I tried to add new campaign but I don't know which option or URL to replace it with mine .any extra  explanation will help thanks .

Comment: You can create home campaigns where you manage your own ads. Then in mediation you specify the cascade between your ad networks (external, i.e. mopub) your home campaigns (self ads) or admob ones.

Comment: Thanks @Miquel for your help it helped me so much but do you have any idea how to prevent admob ads as I need only mine.